# Box2D mouse Joint issue while dragging. TestPoint function return false

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

i'm using box2D mouse joint to drag the objects but i'm stuck in a strange issue that bodies are not responding to the moved function because

```
    if (currentFixture->TestPoint(worldPoint)) {
```

always return false for some specific bodies.

[image]

From above image "Yellow" body is draggable but from some position like centre or bottom of body but not from top.

Note: Bodies are created using "PhysicEditor" so the bodies are "b2PolygonShape".

Edit:
Bodies without Textures... i think the problem is that vertex lines are intersecting each other.

[image]

Edit2: using R.U.B.E same result here too.

[image]

Comment: Try looking at the debug draw display instead of your textures to see exactly what's happening in the physics world.

Comment: I don't use physics editor, but you're body is certainly made of multiple fixtures. Could it be that one of these isn't CCW, or is self-intersecting, that would mean a bug in physics editor ? You could take all the fixtures output by physics editor and test it alone.

Comment: @iforce2d please check the Edit new image is attached.

Comment: @L'angeCarasuelo i'm using a single fixture. But may be that becoz of vertex intersecting each other. Check the edit image..

Comment: Make sure that all the fixtures have been created using a counter-clockwise vertex order.

Comment: @iforce2d but i think physics Editor don't have such option. Can you please suggest any other physics editor for this?

Comment: What do you mean by "same result with RUBE"? This problem is in your program isn't it? Are you doing the TestPoint check for every fixture in these bodies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When bodies have multiple fixtures, you need to check every fixture:

```
bool touchingBody( b2Body* b, b2Vec2 worldPoint ) 
{
    bool bodyIsTouched = false;
    for (b2Fixture* f = b->GetFixtureList(); f; f = f->GetNext()) {
        if ( bodyIsTouched = f->TestPoint(worldPoint) )
            break;
    }
    return bodyIsTouched;
}
```